# Image button visibility: Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having ImageButton14 for the AdminPage but it's marked visible false because I want to check if the admin logged in as admin and the change the visible to true again, but it won't let me... it says "the name (...) does not exist in the current context" but I have ImageButton14...

```
Session["Username"] = Username;
        if (Session["Username"].ToString() == "admin")   
      Response.Redirect("AdminPage.aspx");
```

in the master page I uploaded ImageButton (from the toolbox) and it's ImageButton14. on the properties i checked visible - false.
now before i want to send him to the adminpage i want the imagebutton to change visible true...

Comment: We're going to need to see some code for this.

Comment: You're not giving us enough information.  Can you post the whole error, without the ellipsis?

Comment: That doesn't seem like relevant code.

Comment: We need to see the code pertaining specifically to "ImageButton14".  By the way, "ImageButton14" is a horrible horrible name for a control because it has absolutely no discriminating features.

Comment: @Nick By the time you have that many buttons in one window, you're beyond caring for how they're named.

Comment: @MrLister I have had to deal with "txtBox115.Value".  By the time you have that many buttons in one window, caring should be mandatory.  Stuff like `var x = (txtBox115.Value / txtBox26.Value) * txtBox87.Value)` is migraine fodder.

Comment: @MrLister  -- I'm surprised to see someone with your rep make a statement like that.  Proper naming -- among other bedrock principles of good software -- should never be something you're "beyond".

Comment: What type of project is this?  It sounds like Web-Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also assuming a large chunk, since the information wasn't provided. For clarification, you're receiving:

> "Control doesn't exist in the current context."

This leads me to believe that the you're attempting to determine visibility on another page, instead of the Master Page.  The Control was added to the Master Page, so the check should exist on the Master Page in the Page Load event.

```
if(String.Compare(Session["Username"], "admin") == 0)
     txtAdmin.Visible = true;
```